# How to save and restore all cookies with Selenium RC?

Tags: python, cookies, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm running complex tests that create many cookies for different sections of my web site.

Occasionally I have to restart the browser in the middle a long test and since the Selenium server doesn't modify the base Firefox profile, the cookies evaporate.

Is there any way I can save all of the cookies to a Python variable before terminating the browser and restore them after starting a new browser instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. Look at `getCookie`, `getCookieByName` and `createCookie` methods.

Comment: the get_cookie method doesn't provide the path, domain, and expiry date for each cookie, so it isn't possible to fully restore those parameters with create_cookie.
any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should crate a browser profile and start server for that profile. So all your cookies get saved/modified during every execution. I've gievn these details as answer for another question . [Please refer it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577065/how-do-i-use-selenium-to-login-to-sites-that-require-username-and-password/5595349#5595349). It is given for java client and firefox but I'm sure you can implement it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible using the Chrome-developer-protocoll [getCookies](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getCookies) method.

Using Python, you would execute it as following:

```py
cookies = driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.getCookies", {})
```

Which should return:

```py
name
value
domain
path
expires
size
httpOnly
secure
...
```

and some others (see [Network.Cookie](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-Cookie) Type-Object)