# How do I use Selenium to login to sites that require username and password?

Tags: python, selenium

I am developing an automated test scripts using selenium api with python. But when i run the script from selenium rc its goes to the login page. How will I be able to put in my username and password on that page as it does not contain any sessions or cookies?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question right. But you could use "type" method to type username and password,

Answer (score 8):

Here's the suggestion that was made to me by [Adam Goucher](http://adam.goucher.ca/) on the Selenium IRC channel ( irc://irc.freenode.net/selenium ):

Take advantage of the situation of a completely clean browser cache/cookie history.  Code your test to do the login.

However, instead of hard-coding into your code a username and password, keep a deliberately non-source-code-revisioned configuration file with the username and password locally on the client with the username and password stored there, and have your Selenium client code retrieve the username and password from there when the Selenium code executes.

Answer (score 5):

Thats because selenium server starts new profile for browser everytime, so your saved cookies and bookmarks do not exist on this profile.

First create a profile, for firefox it is given [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles)

then bundle this profile to your selenium server like this

```
    SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer();
    RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
    //rcc.setPort(4444);
    File newFirefoxProfileTemplate = new File(ReadConFile.readcoFile("fiefoxProfilePath"));

    rcc.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(newFirefoxProfileTemplate);
    server = new SeleniumServer(rcc);
    server.start();
    DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",ReadConFile.readcoFile("serverName"));
```

to know your firefoxTemplate click [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox)