# unable to run the application when running from Junit

Tags: selenium, junit4

I am working on developing scripts for a banking application using Selenium on Firefox,  the application take cookies and will store the cookies, 
when i run the application manually and via using selenium IDE in firefox it works fine Now i am converting the selenium commands into JUNIT and when i run (here in the background selenium server.jar is running,)via eclipse the application launches in firefox but creates a seperate profile and in that profile there are no cookies and so my application fails,

Is there any way where i can run the script using Junit and use the firefox browser where it uses the cookies it stores and run the script,

Looking for a positive response,

Regards,
Sairam

Comment: Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577065/how-do-i-use-selenium-to-login-to-sites-that-require-username-and-password/5595349#5595349

Answer (score 0):

try with this command storeCookie(variableName)