# Python Mechanize How to Use Cache Password?

Tags: python, forms, authentication, mechanize

I am experimenting with web automization to optimize my duties. There is a site I am trying to access but I keep getting

```
"httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized".
```

I believe the site is using a cached password located in Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Managed password. Does anybody know how to setup python to login with my cached credentials? Or perhaps a cached password stored somewhere else, since once I log into my computer I can access all work related sites automatically. I am going through a proxy but I configured that properly and tested with google.ca.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize cannot read these stored passwords. But, if you were to look at Selenium you can take advantage of a real browser and then script out the functionality that you require in Selenium and thus take advantage of your stored passwords, through a stored profile.

This answer will give you some guidelines as to how to accomplish what you are looking for: [How do I use Selenium to login to sites that require username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577065/how-do-i-use-selenium-to-login-to-sites-that-require-username-and-password)