# How do you reuse cookies between SeleniumRC sessions?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'd like to run Selenium-RC and have it remember the cookies saved from the last time it was run. Is this possible?

Comment: How are you running Selenium? Almost a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265062/how-to-save-and-restore-all-cookies-with-selenium-rc, although he didn't get a good answer either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium server starts new profile for browser everytime, so your saved cookies and bookmarks do not exist on this profile.

First create a profile, for firefox it is given [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles)

then bundle this profile to your selenium server like this

```
SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer();
RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
//rcc.setPort(4444);
File newFirefoxProfileTemplate = new File(ReadConFile.readcoFile("fiefoxProfilePath"));

rcc.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(newFirefoxProfileTemplate);
server = new SeleniumServer(rcc);
server.start();
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",ReadConFile.readcoFile("serverName"));
```

to know your firefoxTemplate click [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox)

After doing this, manually open browser for this profile and save your cookies, bookmarks , certificates(very helpful for https).

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a **bad** idea to start a test with an existing browser profile, which is why RC starts with a clean one.  But you can make it reuse a profile, by providing **your own** profile template, instead of the one baked into the JAR file.  Check out the RC server's `-firefoxProfileTemplate` option for the details.

Comment: I'm not using Selenium for testing, but for automating web scraping of pages with lots of JavaScript-generated content.