# Browser Automation?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots, python-webbrowser

I want to create a little program with following features.

1. Use proxy in format proxy:port:username:password
2. Choose a proxy sequentialially from list
3. Open http://example.com
4. Fill Details choosing data from data.txt ( CSV )
5. Export Cookie,username,password,email address --> cookie.txt
6. Delete Cookies
7. Log into associated email account and confirm account by visiting
   link sent to that email address.
8. Then cycle through Step1 again.

I read several similar question on stackoverflow.

I planned to use Selenium for this program, but reading comment here [How to save and restore all cookies with Selenium RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265062/how-to-save-and-restore-all-cookies-with-selenium-rc)

> the get_cookie method doesn't provide the path, domain, and expiry
>   date for each cookie, so it isn't possible to fully restore those
>   parameters with create_cookie. any other ideas

And i won't be able to manipulate cookies using method as describe here http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games--active-11117

I want to know easiest way to tackle this problem. I plan to run single threaded application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know selenium, but why not use `mechanize` and `requests` ? Both are awesome.

Comment: They are able to parse/submit/fetch forms from site like facebook?

Comment: I used `requests` to do that, yes. You just need to find which <form> you are trying to submit, to what address, what is the POST data etc. But they are good for it. You might be ok with just `requests`, BTW.

Comment: Thanks: ) . really helpful . I will start working now.